# SQL call in Rails, return object that isn't defined by a model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know how to call SQL to select data from already defined Models, like so:

```
Friend.find_by_sql(["...."])
```

My question is what do I do if I need information that isn't defined by a model?

I have a Meal table, Friend table, and Component table. Components make up Meals, and Friends can be allergic to Components. I have a SQL command (which I can't post here due to confidentiality reasons, but the implementation isn't that relevant anyway) that returns a friend_id and component_id, given a Meal. That is, it returns a list of rows (with two columns each, friend_id and component_id) telling me which Friends are allergic to which Components in a given Meal. But I don't know how to store this in a variable in Ruby and access that information.

To give some pseudocode to give you an idea of what I want to do:

```
@allergies_for_a_meal = ....<INSERT SQL QUERY HERE>...
@friends_who_are_allergic = Friends.find_by_id(@allergies_for_a_meal.friend_id)
```

Can someone give me an idea of the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside an `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass (such as a model) then you'll have access to the current database connection through [`connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-connection); the `connection` has useful methods like [`select_rows`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-select_rows):

```
a = connection.select_rows('select id from ...').map { |r| r[0].to_i }
```

If you're not inside a model class then you really shouldn't be directly messing with the database but you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` if you must.

Comment: @varatis: No, `a` would just contain Fixnums, not model instances or anything complicated like that.

Comment: Alright, so how would I access them? Sorry, I'm pretty new to Ruby

Comment: @varatis: if there was just one then `a[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL View in your database, then create a read-only ActiveRecord model to read data from it.

That way:

- your complex sql is stored in the dbms (and parsed only once).
- you can use all of the usual ActiveRecord accessors and finders to access the data
- you can add *additional* Find constraints to the View's SQL

Note that some Views can be written to, depending on the View's SQL, DBMS, engine, etc. But I recommend against that.